# mongoose get only those documents if all subdocuments pass the criteria

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a `Lesson` schema and it contains an array of `question` subdocuments.
How would I get those lessons where it is marked as completed but all the questions in the array have `isDeleted: true`

I thought of something like

`Lesson.find({ isComplete: true, 'questions.isDeleted': true })`

but that gets the lessons if at least one of the questions is deleted. How would I assert the condition for all of the questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `dot notation` as it flattens the array, What you can do is use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/), this allows the use of `aggregation operators`, like [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/).

Now we can iterate over the array and see if all the documents satisfy the conditions, like so:

```
db.collection.find({
  isComplete: true,
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$questions",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $sum: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $ne: [
                      "$$this.isDeleted",
                      true
                    ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      0
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7g6tfPLtYrV)